# Термин Java Collection framework

Tags: java, коллекции, терминология

> Java collections framework (JCF) — это набор связанных классов и
>   интерфейсов, реализующих широко используемые структуры данных —
>   коллекции.

Здесь не очень понятно набор связанных классов и интерфейсов, реализующие структуры данных - коллекции.
Получается Коллекции это структуры данных аля (List, Set, Queue), а Collection Framework это что тогда получается? Я запутался ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collection Framework это просто название. Java Collections и Java Collection Framework синонимы.

Answer (score 5):

*Набор связанных классов* означает, что эти классы наследуются друг от друга, либо реализуют одни и те же интерфейсы. В это и заключается связь. Получается иерархическое дерево, каждая ветвь которого реализует одну из структур данных (List, Set, Queue, Map etc), а вот всё вышеперечисленное вместе называют *Сollection Framework*.

[image: Collection framework hierarchy]